# Restful Routing Conventions using Expo Router

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

I'm having issues wrapping my head around how to set up Expo Router to use standard restful routing conventions. This primarily has to do with routes like `/organizations/1/edit` and things of that nature.

My file structure is something like this:

```
app/
  (drawer)/
    _layout.tsx
    organizations/
      _layout.tsx
      [id]/
        show.tsx
        edit.tsx
```

I don't want to have to use `organizations/1/show` as the route in this case. I simply want it to be `organizations/1`. This *ideally* needs to remain in the stack defined in the `_layout.tsx` in the `/organizations` dir.

The goal is to end up with `organizations/1` actually rendering show page while maintaining REST convention by also having `organizations/1/edit` give back the edit page.

I have tried using a file structure more like:

```
app/
  (drawer)/
    _layout.tsx
    organizations/
      _layout.tsx
      [id].tsx
      edit.tsx
```

This doesn't solve the problem however. I'm aware of [Dynamic Routes](https://docs.expo.dev/routing/navigating-pages/), but it doesn't seem like I should have to delegate to specific screens based on the `[...rest].tsx` files with control flow to render certain components. (At least that's how I was interpreting it.)

Am I missing something here? Or is Dynamic Routing supposed to be the way to accomplish this?